# Fail to join large groups

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two data structures with the same structure:

```
{(id, (record1, record2, record3))}
```

I want to join them, by on the value of `record1`. In order to do that I wrote this script:

```
data_1_group = group data_1 by $1.record1; 
data_2_group = group data_2 by $1.record1; 
jj = join data_1_group by group, data_2_group by group;
```

But, since the both `data_1` and `data_2` contains millions of records while `record1` can assume only 20 different values, the groups are very large and the script runs out of memory and fails.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That would depend, are all combinations useful for your further processing?

Comment: If you mean conbinations of data_1->record1 and data_1->record1, yes they are.

Comment: It is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732456/how-to-optimize-a-group-by-statement-in-pig-latin/11265842#11265842 You would need to flatten and join on more than id, would need to use a column from record and after you get results group on ID.